# Internet explorer 11 adding random styles to elements, etc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a couple of pages with tables containing checkboxes in the first column, in internet explorer 11 the table appears like this:

Some images are changed, some removed, checkboxes change colour, etc.

[image]

but in chrome and firefox it appears like this, as it should:

[image]

When inspecting the source in IE11 it all looks fine, sometimes the colours of the checkboxes change when i move the mouse over an unrelated element, all very strange.

Update - the same thing happens on other computers in my office when they have IE11 installed

Update - Running IE11 on Windows 8.1

Any ideas?

Comment: A problem with caching maybe?

Comment: good thought, just cleared cache and hard refreshed the page, every refresh just makes different checkboxes change colour :p

Comment: That's a really weird behaviour.

Comment: Please post the related code..

Comment: Can you verify that this happens on another computer with IE11?

Comment: Yup tested on multiple computers using ie11, all the same issue.

Comment: Try to add `zoom:1` in your css. `HasLayout` ie problem maybe...

Comment: To best assist in resolving these types of issues, we'll need a working demo. I would try to remove as much of the surrounding elements on the page as possible to see if I can reproduce the issues with nothing more than basic markup and styles, absent of any surrounding noise. Can you provide a demo like that?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a "common" internet explorer rendering-artifact-bug. (I couldn't find a good article for it right now).

Almost all Internet Explorer's have problems with elements having a layout or not. A simple fix is usually to add a `position: relative;` to one or some of the parent elements (don't ask exactly which one)...

Comment: I was actually going to give the same suggestion :). this trick works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. It was a same issue with older MSIEs, when I moved the window outside of the screen, then back, the background color just disappeared (during the window moving, strange). MSIE "supports" two modes, and the standard mode can be triggered by defining any position/size attribute. The best way is to define something which has no effects, e.g. zoom to 1.
2. Maybe you should set different HTML header for select the proper [rendering mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

If none of above works, there are plenty of MSIE-tricks yet!